# Reemplazar dato en un arreglo

Tags: javascript

Tengo este arreglo

```
var autos= [{
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
}];
```

y tengo una variable

```
var precioDescuento = 6120
```

Lo que estoy tratando de realizar es reemplazar el precio de **73710** por el de **6120**

Lo estaba itentando realizar de esta manera pero me sale un error ¿alguna idea?

```
autos.push([ "Precio": precioDescuento ]);

console.log(autos);
```

El resultado final  seria

```
var autos= [{
        "Modelo": "Mazda",
        "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
        "Precio": 6120
    }];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es primero que todo recorrer tu `array` (ya que lo que tienes es un `array` de objetos) y sobreescribir los datos creando un nuevo `array` con los mismos. Es necesario hacer una condición para seleccionar la propiedad que quieras cambiar de alguno de los objetos contenidos en el `array` en caso de que no quieras que se aplique a todos los objetos.

Agregué un nuevo objeto para que veas mejor el funcionamiento del código:

```js
var autos = [{
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
}, {
    "Modelo": "Audi",
    "Referencia": "R8",
    "Precio": 73710
}];

var precioDescuento = 6120;
var modelo = "Mazda";

autos.map(function(dato){
  if(dato.Modelo == modelo){
    dato.Precio = precioDescuento;
  }
  
  return dato;
});

console.log(autos)
```

Answer (score 5):

Espero sea lo que buscas.

Para cambiar un valor de un arreglo es simplemente poner la clave en este caso 
`autos[0].precio` el `0` representa en primer objeto del array y la clave `precio` y le asignamos con el `=` el nuevo valor.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
var autos= [{
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
}];
var precioDescuento = 6120
autos[0].Precio = precioDescuento

console.log(autos);
```

saludos espero te ayude

> **Nota**:Si tu array tiene varios objetos lo único que tienes que hacer es un `for` para recorrerlo y asignarle el `index` en vez de el `0` algo así:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
  autos[i].Precio = precioDescuento
 }
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
var autos= [{
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
},{
    "Modelo": "corola",
    "Referencia": "corola 2",
    "Precio": 45221
},{
    "Modelo": "chevrolet",
    "Referencia": "chevrolet 9",
    "Precio": 5090
}];


var precioDescuento = 6120
for (var i = 0; i < autos.length; i++) {
      autos[i].Precio = precioDescuento
     }
console.log(autos);
```

o también puedes usar la function `forEach` para recorrer el array seria algo asi

```
autos.forEach(function(item){
  item.precio = precioDescuento
})
```

> El método **forEach()** ejecuta la función indicada una vez por cada elemento del array.

### Sintaxis forEach

```
 arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // tu iterador
 }[, thisArg]);
```

**Descripción**

> forEach() ejecuta la función callback una vez por cada elemento presente en el array en orden ascendente. No es invocada para índices que han sido eliminados o que no hayan sido inicializados (Ej. sobre arrays sparse)

```js
var autos= [{
    "Modelo": "Mazda",
    "Referencia": "Mazda 6",
    "Precio": 73710
},{
    "Modelo": "corola",
    "Referencia": "corola 2",
    "Precio": 45221
},{
    "Modelo": "chevrolet",
    "Referencia": "chevrolet 9",
    "Precio": 5090
}];


var precioDescuento = 6120
autos.forEach(function(item){
      item.precio = precioDescuento
    })
console.log(autos);
```

Comment: Y si el Array tuviera 100 objetos tendría que quemar los 100 índices ...?

Comment: ya lo explique amigo haces un `for` al `array` y listo.

Comment: es un cambio simple y seria complejo para alguien nuevo usar `map` para recorrer y cambiar un arreglo me parece que si es algo simple es mejor con un `for`

Comment: Recorrer un array con for me parece personalmente una mala práctica, para eso es mejor usar Array.prototype.forEach que es el método que 
 implementa JS para recorrer un array... al usar un for yo lo veo como usar un h1 para un párrafo, funciona igual (dándole estilos obviamente) pero no es correcto, saludos!

Comment: tienes toda la razón es que me parece mas fácil de ver y entender para los novatos pero voy a dejar un ejemplo con `forEach` muchas gracias

Comment: Es una observación frecuente que, cuando se recorre un array por medio de un ciclo for (desaconsejado) del que no conocemos la longitud, dereferenciemos la propiedad length del array recorrido asignándo primero su valor a una variable y, luego, utilizar el valor de dicha variable para el ciclo for, como en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989270/for-loop-performance-storing-array-length-in-a-variable.